# How to project a texture/shape to specific part of a mesh in Three.js?

Tags: javascript, three.js, mesh

I’d like to project a texture or some shape ( transparent - ring, circle) to a mesh (but to a specific part). For example, in games we select/click an enemy or NPC then we see some circle under the character which indicates a selection. That circle changes its shape based on the mesh (height, slope), you can check the following images.

I’d like to do that, but I’m not sure how to do it, perfectly - so far I tried to raycast a mesh and got the vertices normal and applied the rotation but when it comes to more complex part of the mesh this does not work well enough. I think I need to use shaders? Is there any resource I can check?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not as difficult as it seems.

Modify the ground material with `.onBeforeCompile`, passing position of the selected object in a uniform, and then process it in shaders.

In the code snippet, click a button to select the respective object, so the selection mark will follow it on the ground:

```css
body{
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}
#selections {
  width: 100px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
button.selected{
  color: #00ff32;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="selections" style="position: absolute;border: 1px solid yellow;"></div>
<script type="module">
import * as THREE from "https://cdn.skypack.dev/three@0.133";
import {
  OrbitControls
} from "https://cdn.skypack.dev/three@0.133/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js";

let scene = new THREE.Scene();
let camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(60, innerWidth / innerHeight, 1, 1000);
camera.position.set(0, 5, 8);
camera.lookAt(scene.position);
let renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
  antialias: true
});
renderer.setSize(innerWidth, innerHeight);
renderer.setClearColor(0x404040);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

let controls = new OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);

let light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 1);
light.position.setScalar(1);
scene.add(
    light,
  new THREE.AmbientLight(0xffffff, 0.5)
);

let objects = new Array(5).fill(0).map((p,idx)=>{return setObject(idx)});
//console.log(objects);
let selected = objects[0];

let g = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(10, 10, 5, 5);
g.rotateX(-Math.PI * 0.5);
for(let i = 0; i < g.attributes.position.count; i++){
    g.attributes.position.setY(i, (Math.random() * 2 - 1) * 0.75);
}
g.computeVertexNormals();
let uniforms = {
    selection: {value: new THREE.Vector3()}
}
let m = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
    color: 0x003264,
    map: new THREE.TextureLoader().load("https://threejs.org/examples/textures/water.jpg"),
  onBeforeCompile: shader => {
    shader.uniforms.selection = uniforms.selection;
    shader.vertexShader = `
        varying vec3 vPos;
      ${shader.vertexShader}
    `.replace(
        `#include <begin_vertex>`,
      `#include <begin_vertex>
        vPos = transformed;
      `
    );
    shader.fragmentShader = `
        #define ss(a, b, c) smoothstep(a, b, c)
        uniform vec3 selection;
      varying vec3 vPos;
      ${shader.fragmentShader}
    `.replace(
        `#include <dithering_fragment>`,
      `#include <dithering_fragment>
      
        // shape
        float dist = distance(selection.xz, vPos.xz);
        float r = 0.25;
        
        float shape = (ss(r-0.1, r, dist)*0.75 + 0.25) - ss(r, r + 0.1, dist);
        
        vec3 col = mix(gl_FragColor.rgb, vec3(0, 1, 0.25), shape);
        gl_FragColor = vec4(col, gl_FragColor.a);
      `
    );
    //console.log(shader.fragmentShader)
  }
});

let o = new THREE.Mesh(g, m);
scene.add(o);

window.addEventListener("resize", onResize);

let clock = new THREE.Clock();

renderer.setAnimationLoop(_ => {
    
  let t = clock.getElapsedTime() * 0.5;
  
  objects.forEach(obj => {
    let ud = obj.userData;
    obj.position.x = Math.cos(t * ud.scaleX + ud.initPhase) * 4.75;
    obj.position.y = 1;
    obj.position.z = Math.sin(t * ud.scaleZ + ud.initPhase) * 4.75;
  })
  
  o.worldToLocal(uniforms.selection.value.copy(selected.position));
  
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
  
})

function setObject(idx){
    let g = new THREE.SphereGeometry(0.25);
  let m = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color: 0x7f7f7f * Math.random() + 0x7f7f7f});
  let o = new THREE.Mesh(g, m);
  o.userData = {
    initPhase: Math.PI * 2 * Math.random(),
    scaleX: Math.random() * 0.5 + 0.5,
    scaleZ: Math.random() * 0.5 + 0.5
  }
  scene.add(o);
  
  let btn = document.createElement("button");
  btn.innerText = "Object " + idx;
  selections.appendChild(btn);
  btn.addEventListener("click", event => {
    selections.querySelectorAll("button").forEach(b => {b.classList.remove("selected")});
    btn.classList.add("selected");
    selected = o
  });
  
  return o;
}

function onResize(event) {
  camera.aspect = innerWidth / innerHeight;
  camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
  renderer.setSize(innerWidth, innerHeight);
}

</script>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! The demo looks so nice.

Comment: @ErtuğrulÇetin You're welcome :)

Comment: This is great! Would it be possible to explain a bit how it works, e.g. I tried to change the size of the circle (managed by multiplying dist with values from 0.01  to 0.3) but it's just not intuitive how to relate to those values. Would really appreciate any explanation of why this works as it does, or pointers to where I can read more. Currently going through https://thebookofshaders.com/ and figuring out the principles but variables like vPos in your example throw me off...

Comment: @Cristian You can use radius not as a constant of `float r = 0.25;`, but pass it in the uniform, so you'll be able to change it dynamically. You can ask questions also on the forum: https://discourse.threejs.org/

Comment: Right. thanks, I think I tried to change the radius but increasing the value didn't make it bigger. Is there some kind of way where I can map these values to meaning? E.g. what does 1.0 mean and what does 0.0 mean? I would expect radius = 1.0 to make a circle as big as my mesh surface, but doesn't do so.

Comment: I recommend watching this course into shaders - this is really helpful trying to understand these concepts: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kfM-yu0iQBk 
I think I'm getting closer to an understanding of what the code above does.